# spacemacs override keybinding for Edebug mode

Tags: spacemacs

```
(define-key evil-evilified-state-map (kbd "C-b") 'evil-scroll-page-up)
```

is picked up by edebug-mode in spacemacs

I want to override it

```
  (evilified-state-evilify-map edebug-mode-map
    :eval-after-load edebug
    :bindings
    "C-f" #'forward-char
    "C-b" #'backward-char
    "C-d" #'delete-char

    )
```

it has no effect, (I tried removing "eval-after-load") as well,

How can I overload `evilified` key binding (I don't want to turn it off by

```
 (evil-set-initial-state 'edebug-mode 'emacs)
```